# Переменная меняющегося типа - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, переменные, типы-данных

Возник такой вот вопрос: возможно ли одной переменной присваивать различные значения в зависимости от условия?

Допустим, есть переменная Sticker, нужно чтобы при выполнении одного условия она была типом TextBox, а при выполнении другого - Label (например).

Вот фрагмент кода для понимания:

```
// Нажатие клавиши добавления стикера
private void AddTaskButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (j == 5) // (за место "j" используйте любое другое условие)
    {
        CreateTransparentSticker(ref Sticker);
    }

    else
    {
        CreateUsualSticker(ref Sticker);
    }

    Sticker.Left = 55; // возникает ошибка  CS0103 - Имя "Sticker" не существует в текущем контексте

    Sticker.Top = 80;

    Controls.Add(Sticker);
    Sticker.BringToFront();
}

// Создание обычного стикера
private void CreateUsualSticker(ref TextBox Sticker)
{
    Sticker = new TextBox
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        Cursor = Cursors.IBeam,
        ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical,
        Text = "",
        Size = new Size(140, 140),
        AcceptsReturn = true,
        AcceptsTab = true,
        AllowDrop = true,
        Multiline = true,
        ReadOnly = false,
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 200),
        TabStop = true,
        WordWrap = true
    };
}

// Создание прозрачного стикера (в данном случае элемента типа Label)
private void CreateTransparentSticker(ref Label Sticker)
{
    Sticker = new Label()
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        Cursor = Cursors.IBeam,
        Text = "",
        Size = new Size(140, 140),
        AllowDrop = true,
        TabStop = true
    };
}
```

Буду очень признателен за исчерпывающий ответ!

Comment: Наследниками какого класса являются и TextBox, и Label?

Comment: @MBo, стандартными наследниками класса формы (System.Windows.Forms.TextBox и System.Windows.Forms.Label)

Comment: Ну какой формы... `Наследование` в справке посмотрите.  Контролы это, наследники общего базового типа Control

Comment: @MBo, вот этой формы: public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
(_надеюсь, вы это имели в виду?_ )

Comment: Ну нет же. Форма ваша - наследник указанного вами типа, а компоненты на ней - наследники Control. Может, вы путаете владельца компонентов (обычно форма) и родителей в цепочке наследования.  (Если на пальцах, то ваш директор - не ваш отец)

Comment: @MBo, в таком случае TextBox и Label являются наследниками PictureBox'а под именем Desk, созданного на форме.
_Спасибо, что подметили! А то в моём коде, действительно, этот момент был непонятен (теперь я подправил на корректную версию)_

Comment: К сожалению , вы таки не поняли разницу между наследованием и владением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам надо, чтобы переменная меняла тип, значит вы скорее всего что то делаете не так.

В вашем случае достаточно просто привести все к базовому типу.

```
    private void AddTaskButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = null;
        int j = 0;
        
        if (j == 5) // (за место "j" используйте любое другое условие)
        {
            control = CreateTransparentSticker();
        }

        else
        {
             control = CreateUsualSticker();
        }

        control.Left = 55;
        control.Top = 80;

        Controls.Add(control);
        control.BringToFront();
    }


    private TextBox CreateUsualSticker()
    {
        return new TextBox
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            Cursor = Cursors.IBeam,
            ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical,
            Text = "",
            Size = new Size(140, 140),
            AcceptsReturn = true,
            AcceptsTab = true,
            AllowDrop = true,
            Multiline = true,
            ReadOnly = false,
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 200),
            TabStop = true,
            WordWrap = true
        };
    }

    // Создание прозрачного стикера (в данном случае элемента типа Label)
    private Label CreateTransparentSticker()
    {
        return new Label()
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            Cursor = Cursors.IBeam,
            Text = "",
            Size = new Size(140, 140),
            AllowDrop = true,
            TabStop = true
        };
    }
```

Comment: Всё работает, только из-за этого всплывает другая проблема  - при дальнейшем использовании "стикера" ему после невозможно задать свойство ReadOnly = true (Sticker.ReadOnly = true;). В моей программе данное свойство необходимо 

Comment: в дальнейшем выдаёт ошибку :
Ошибка CS1061 "Control" не содержит определения "ReadOnly", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ReadOnly", принимающий тип "Control" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: @Chaos_Sower а как вы `Label` собираетесь менять `ReadOnly`? У нее нет этого свойства. `if (control is TextBox tb) { tb.ReadOnly = true; }`

Comment: @Chaos_Sower потому что стикер - это не обязательно TextBox и не обязан иметь поля, которые есть у TextBox. Вы можете стрелять себе в ногу `if (control is TextBox) ((TextBox)control).ReadOnly = true;` или вы можете в вопросе описать свою задачу, так как есть вероятнсть, что ваш подход к решению вашей задачи неидеален

Comment: @aepot все время забываю про эти новые фишки сишарпа =) Новые для меня, как чела, что не пишет на дотнете уже несколько лет.

Comment: @tym32167 Сам в шоке, было `if (text?.Length > 0)` стало `if (text is { Length : > 0 })`, это абсолютно эквивалентный код :) То ли ещё будет...

Comment: @aepot, если использовать одно и тоже условие (из AddTaskButton_Click), то если наступает условие "else",- Sticker становится Textbox'ом. При дальнейшем использовании Sticker ему нельзя придать свойство ReadOnly, даже когда его тип - TextBox.

Для наглядности:

private void Button_Click(Control Sticker)
{
    Sticker.ReadOnly = false;
    Sticker.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}

Comment: @Chaos_Sower я же вам написал, как это сделать! `if (control is TextBox tb) { tb.ReadOnly = true; }` будьте внимательней

Comment: @aepot, извините, ваш ответ не прогрузился на тот момент

Comment: Да, теперь всё работает даже лучше, чем отлично!  Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Chaos_Sower очень рекомендую изучить полностью https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ это не займет много времени